# JS increase/decrease multiple input number variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying toincrease and decrease value of 'val' class and i'll use them more than once in one page. Also i need to set MIN and MAX values for them.

```
   <input type="button" value="-" class="decreaseVal">
   <input type="number" min ="1" max="22" value="20" class="val" disabled>
   <input type="button" value="+" class="increaseVal">


   // JS CODE THAT I TRY
   $(".decreaseVal").click(function() {
      var num = $(this).next('input').val();
   });


   $(".increaseVal").click(function() {
      var num = $(this).prev('input').val();
   });
```

I can get their values but i am not able to change them. Any advice guys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```js
$(".decreaseVal").click(function() {
  var input_el=$(this).next('input');
  var v= input_el.val()-1;
  if(v>=input_el.attr('min'))
  input_el.val(v)
});


$(".increaseVal").click(function() {
  var input_el=$(this).prev('input');
  var v= input_el.val()*1+1;
  if(v<=input_el.attr('max'))
  input_el.val(v)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="-" class="decreaseVal">
<input type="number" min="1" max="22" value="20" class="val" disabled>
<input type="button" value="+" class="increaseVal">
```

Comment: This will set value beyond the max and lesser to the min